# How Azure Event Hub Subscription access the deadletter container?

Tags: azure, security, rbac, azure-eventgrid, azure-storage-account

How the azure event hub sub can access to deadletter container ?

Because I never gave any explicit permissions like storage account contributor or I never gave any access key while creating the dead-letter in the eventgrid sub. In such case how come the event hub sub can able to create the blobs inside the container which we choose ?

Seeing from the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery#set-dead-letter-location) there is no such information. All i see is like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found on of the reason how could the storage account can communicate (network) to event grid, because of the **[Exception to the Trusted Azure Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#exceptions)**

By default every storage account will be enabled for this option

[image]

So, being my event grid is a exception case (already a trusted azure service). With this I think the storage account can communicate to event grid no matter how secure my storage account is.

But the main part of the question which is how could the event grid gain the access without I given the access keys or RBAC. Which is still weird. This is now traced with [Microsoft directly](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/81891)